# How do i place this DataGrid in Material Ui correctly?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-design, mui-datatable

[image: Dashboard Image]

I have tried  a lot of different solutions to make this grid perfectly fit in, i can not seem to understand material ui sizing within this space.
As you can see the column titles are missing, and it's not centered in the middle.

I have used the clipped drawer also from MUI which is placed inside of Box

```
import * as React from "react";
import { DataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import { Container, Grid, Paper, Box } from "@mui/material";

const columns = [
  { field: "id", headerName: "ID", width: 90 },
  {
    field: "firstName",
    headerName: "First name",
    width: 150,
    editable: true,
  },
  {
    field: "lastName",
    headerName: "Last name",
    width: 150,
    editable: true,
  },
  {
    field: "age",
    headerName: "Age",
    type: "number",
    width: 110,
    editable: true,
  },
  {
    field: "fullName",
    headerName: "Full name",
    description: "This column has a value getter and is not sortable.",
    sortable: false,
    width: 160,
    valueGetter: (params) =>
      `${params.row.firstName || ""} ${params.row.lastName || ""}`,
  },
];

const rows = [
  { id: 1, lastName: "Snow", firstName: "Jon", age: 35 },
  { id: 2, lastName: "Lannister", firstName: "Cersei", age: 42 },
  { id: 3, lastName: "Lannister", firstName: "Jaime", age: 45 },
  { id: 4, lastName: "Stark", firstName: "Arya", age: 16 },
  { id: 5, lastName: "Targaryen", firstName: "Daenerys", age: null },
  { id: 6, lastName: "Melisandre", firstName: null, age: 150 },
  { id: 7, lastName: "Clifford", firstName: "Ferrara", age: 44 },
  { id: 8, lastName: "Frances", firstName: "Rossini", age: 36 },
  { id: 9, lastName: "Roxie", firstName: "Harvey", age: 65 },
];

export default function DataGridDemo() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Paper component={Box} width={1} height={700}>
        <DataGrid
          rows={rows}
          columns={columns}
          pageSize={5}
          rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
          checkboxSelection
          disableSelectionOnClick
        />
      </Paper>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `<Toolbar/>`

`import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';`

````
<Container>
   <Toolbar/>
      <Paper component={Box} width={1} height={700}>
        <DataGrid
          rows={rows}
          columns={columns}
          pageSize={5}
          rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
          checkboxSelection
          disableSelectionOnClick
        />
      </Paper>
    </Container>```
````

Answer (score -1):

Put your code on codesandbox.io so that It easy to figure out the problem

Comment: It is nota an answer, it is a comment